# How to create env variables in powershell in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to create environment variable in Jenkinsfile which will store the name of the file with .sln extension in current workspace. I have no ide how to do it. I've tried to create it with powershell

```bsh
$project_to_publish = (dir *.sln).BaseName
```

but I don't know how to make it environmental. Any ideas?

Comment: PowerShell session that you run from Jenkins run in a _child process_. Child processes cannot set environment variables for their calling (parent) process. Instead, you must return _output_ from your PowerShell command (possibly a string containing name-value pair such as `project_to_publish=Foo`) and set the environment variable on the Jenkins side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a pipeline script you don't have to use PowerShell and can use [findFiles](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) instead.

```
def files = findFiles(glob: '*.sln')
println files[0]
```

In a freestyle job it would depend on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the variable in the environment section of your pipeline and the update it in your powershell script with $env:variablename.

Comment: This does not work.  You cannot directly update the environment variable from the PowerShell script.  The updated value will be in the PowerShell script, but accessing from outside the specific PowerShell script will return the original value.  [See Dibakar Aditya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63140774/641833)